# What do I have to change in order to run Tomcat in Production?

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, production-environment

I have a tomcat 7.0.42 server running on my production environment which is ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-Bit. I compiled the APR connector and activated it.

What else do I have to change in order to make my tomcat production ready?

Answer (score 0):

Check the links below:

- [Security setup](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-security)
- [Performance setup](http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=836)

Comment: Link above for "Performance Setup" is fairly dubious. Solution for PermGen leaks is to increase heap space? :(

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat comes with a reasonable default configuration that will work perfectly fine in production. As always, your environment may have special needs. If you provide some details, perhaps someone else can help. As stated, your question is not possible to answer.

If it were me, I would at least change the HTTP connector from the default BIO to the NIO connector regardless of other factors. Everything else will depend upon your requirements.

Comment: I wrote that I still use the APR Connector which is much faster than the NIO Connector. What else should I speed up?

Comment: APR vs NIO performance depends upon your use cases. SSL is much faster with APR because OpenSSL is faster than JSSE. But you didn't say you were using SSL, now did you?

Comment: I'm surprised you are getting "much faster" performance from the APR connector. My last benchmarking was done ab out 2 years ago, but I found the NIO and APR connectors to be comparable. You can [see my data and write-up if you'd like](http://people.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202010/).